# Should I use Touches from NSSet or Touches from UIEvent in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I noticed there are alot of different ways of handling input touches. (Multitouch)

Function like

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Should I directly use the touches (first argument) or should I use `[event allTouches]` (second argument)

I noticed that some people even use

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
```

I check from the Apple documentation and anyObject is just return one of the object from NSSet, isn't that a bit random? I don't see any useful of calling this if u are doing multitouch where the id for each touch is important.

I also know that `[event allTouches]` actually return all the touches in all windows but when we are doing in cocos2d, I thought most of the time we are only dealing with one window?

So let say my game only has 1 view (openGL view) at a time, so which touches should I use?
first argument touches or `[event allTouches]`?

Hope someone could clear me out on this :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use multitouch you should use this function:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

If you would like to use one touch you should use this function:

```
- (void)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

If you use multitouch and you need a first touch you should use first argument of NSSet touches, for second touch you should use second argument and etc.